# Need Help! Angular 2 File/Image upload via API

Tags: angular, file-upload, laravel-5.3, angular-file-upload

I'm stack around uploading image/file using Angular2. I don't like to add any plugins to upload file in angular2. Is there any simple way to upload image via API using Angular2 without any third party extension ?

> NB: i am using laravel as server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Template

```html
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
<button type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

2. The Service

```js
export class FileUpload{
/* This method will worked for single file upload, if you need multipule file upload then replace formData.append("uploads", files[i], files[i].name); to formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
*/
makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var formData: any = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads", files[i], files[i].name);
            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
}
```

3. The Component

```js
export class AppComponent {
  filesToUpload: Array<File>;

  constructor(private _fileUpload:FileUpload) {
        this.filesToUpload = [];
  }

  upload() {
        this._fileUpload.makeFileRequest("/api/admin/upload-slider-image", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
        this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what needs to be done/considered when uploading Images (or files) from Angular 2 to a server.

1. Create an Image upload component using the following elements. 
   The template:

```html
<div class="image-upload"
     fileDrop
     [accept]="['image/*']"
     (isFileOver)="fileOver($event)"
     (fileDrop)="fileChange($event)"
     [ngClass]="{'file-is-over': isFileOver}"
>
  <div class="file-upload hr-inline-group">
    <label class="upload-button">
      <span>{{buttonCaption}}</span>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        (change)="fileChange(input.files)"
        #input>
    </label>   

    <div class="drag-box-message">{{dropBoxMessage}}</div>
  </div>
    <div *ngIf="fileSizeExceeded" class="drag-box-message">
        <p>Please upload a file less than 2 MB.</p>
    </div>

  <div *ngIf="preview" class="image-container hr-inline-group">
    <div
      class="image"
      *ngFor="let file of files"
      [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+ file.src +')'}"
    >
      <div *ngIf="file.pending" class="loading-overlay">
        <div class="spinningCircle"></div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!file.pending" class="x-mark" (click)="deleteFile(file)">
        <span class="close"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Your component class, which needs to be exported.

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageService, Header } from "../../../services/content/image.service";

export class FileHolder {
    public serverResponse: any;
    public pending: boolean = false;
    constructor(public src: string, public file: File) { }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'image-upload',
    templateUrl: "app/components/controls/image-upload/image-upload.component.html",
    styles: [
        `
.image-upload {
  --common-radius: 3px;
  --active-color: #33CC99;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: var(--common-radius);
  border: #d0d0d0 dashed 1px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.file-is-over {
  border-color: var(--active-color);
  border-style: solid;
}

.hr-inline-group:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.file-upload {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.drag-box-message {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  color: #9b9b9b;
  font-weight: 600;
}

label.upload-button input[type=file] {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: -99999px;
}

.upload-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--active-color);
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(148,148,148,0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(148,148,148,0.6);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(148,148,148,0.6);
}

.upload-button:active span{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 1px;
}

.image-container {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.image {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px;
  width: 86px;
  height: 86px;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}

.x-mark {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .7;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px;
}

.close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: .7;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
.x-mark:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 16px;
  width: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.loading-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .7;
}

.spinningCircle {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  -webkit-animation: spinner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.085, 0.625, 0.855, 0.360);
  animation: spinner 2s infinite cubic-bezier(0.085, 0.625, 0.855, 0.360);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinner {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);

  }
}
`
    ]
})
export class ImageUploadComponent {
    @Input() max: number = 100;
    @Input() url: string;
    @Input() headers: Header[];
    @Input() preview: boolean = true;

    @Output()
    isPending: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    @Output()
    onFileUploadFinish: EventEmitter<FileHolder> = new EventEmitter<FileHolder>();
    @Output()
    onRemove: EventEmitter<FileHolder> = new EventEmitter<FileHolder>();

    private files: FileHolder[] = [];

    private fileCounter: number = 0;
    private pendingFilesCounter: number = 0;
    private fileSizeExceeded: boolean = false;

    private isFileOver: boolean = false;

    @Input()
    buttonCaption: string = "Select Images";
    @Input()
    dropBoxMessage: string = "Drop your images here!";

    constructor(private imageService: ImageService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imageService.setUrl(this.url);
    }

    fileChange(files) {
        let remainingSlots = this.countRemainingSlots();
        let filesToUploadNum = files.length > remainingSlots ? remainingSlots : files.length;

        if (this.url && filesToUploadNum != 0) {
            this.isPending.emit(true);
        }

        this.fileCounter += filesToUploadNum;

        this.uploadFiles(files, filesToUploadNum);
    }

    private uploadFiles(files, filesToUploadNum) {
        for (let i = 0; i < filesToUploadNum; i++) {
            let file = files[i];

            console.log('FILE SIZE: ', file.size);

            if (file.size > 3000000) {
                this.fileSizeExceeded = true;
                return;
            }

            let img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {
                let fileHolder: FileHolder = new FileHolder(event.target.result, file);

                fileHolder.serverResponse = `good boy: ${i}`;

                this.uploadSingleFile(fileHolder);

                this.files.push(fileHolder);

            }, false);


            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    private uploadSingleFile(fileHolder: FileHolder) {
        if (this.url) {
            this.pendingFilesCounter++;
            fileHolder.pending = true;

            this.imageService.postImage(fileHolder.file, this.headers).subscribe(response => {
                fileHolder.serverResponse = response;
                this.onFileUploadFinish.emit(fileHolder);
                fileHolder.pending = false;
                if (--this.pendingFilesCounter == 0) {
                    this.isPending.emit(false);
                }
            });

        } else {
            this.onFileUploadFinish.emit(fileHolder);
        }
    }

    private deleteFile(file: FileHolder): void {
        let index = this.files.indexOf(file);
        this.files.splice(index, 1);
        this.fileCounter--;

        this.onRemove.emit(file);
    }

    fileOver(isOver) {
        this.isFileOver = isOver;
    }

    private countRemainingSlots() {
        return this.max - this.fileCounter;
    }
}
```

3. Import it into your App module, and include it as part of the declarations.
4. Now this component can be used anywhere to upload an image.
5. This component takes care of adding request headers that can contain authentication tokens that will be used by the server.

Hope that helps.